# Is it possible to make browser on server side?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, browser, virtual

I want to export charts in pdf files.
What I want to do is to save somehow images of charts in a temp place and then use this images to generate pdf files to finally export them.
I have the understanding that in case I do not have the image on a screen (a browser), it would not be possible to catch it somehow from the browser, as I do these calculations on the server side.

Normally I think in other cases could catch images by:

1. Create canvas
2. Write anything on a screen
3. Display it on a screen or save it
4. Save it and send it somehow to the server to
       export it to client

The question is: Is it possible to make a virtual browser on the server and then write there the javascript?
If we want to do it on a server we have to do it programmatically as makes a virtual screen
and then probably we can call it as a function and put javascript and HTML inside and then run.

Is there a thing to use it as it virtually opens a browser window and then write the HTML and javascript and then save it?

Comment: You don't need a canvas, I'm sure there are image and rendering/drawing libraries for node.js.

Comment: Why are you rendering your charts on a browser. You can do it server side.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to look into "headless Chrome"

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome